# Get text of a paragraph with all the markup (and their content) removed

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

How can I get only the text of the node `<p>` which has other tags in it like:

```html
<p>hello my website is <a href="www.website.com">click here</a> <b>test</b></p>
```

I only want "`hello my website is`"

This is what I tried:

```ruby
begin
  node = html_doc.css('p')
  node.each do |node|
    node.children.remove
  end
  return (node.nil?) ? ''  : node.text
rescue
  return ''
end
```

Comment: Just to clarify, did you want that to be the output?  Not: "hello my website is click here test"?

Comment: Hi @Hector,that is what im trying to get "hello my website is" just want to remove all the child tags with its content remaining only the parent content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update 2**: all right, well you are removing all children with `node.children.remove`, including the text nodes, a proposed solution might look like:

```
# 1. select all <p> nodes
doc.css('p').
  # 2. map children, and flatten
  map { |node| node.children }.flatten.
  # 3. select text nodes only
  select { |node| node.text? }.
  # 4. get text and join
  map { |node| node.text }.join(' ').strip
```

This sample returns "hello my website is", but note that `doc.css('p')` als finds `<p>` tags within `<p>` tags.

**Update**: sorry, misread your question, you only want "hello my website is", see solution above, original answer:

Not directly with nokogiri, but the sanitize gem might be an option: https://github.com/rgrove/sanitize/

```
Sanitize.clean(html, {}) # => " hello my website is click here test "
```

FYI, it uses nokogiri internally.

Comment: thanks @Iwe but i got to get only "hello my website is" removing all childs in the <p>

Comment: @Prasaanth, sorry misread your question - updated my question with a working solution for your problem (i.e. removing childs)

Answer (score 1):

Your test case did not include any interesting text interleaved with the markup.

- If you want to turn `<p>Hello <b>World</b>!</p>` into `"Hello !"`, then removing the children is one way to do it. Simpler (and less destructive) is to just find all the text nodes and join them:

  ```
  require 'nokogiri'
  html = Nokogiri::HTML('<p>Hello <b>World</b>!</p>')

  # Find the first paragraph (in this case the only one)
  para = html.at('p') 

  # Find all the text nodes that are children (not descendants),
  # change them from nodes into the strings of text they contain,
  # and then smush the results together into one big string.
  p para.search('text()').map(&:text).join 
  #=> "Hello !"
  ```
- If you want to turn `<p>Hello <b>World</b>!</p>` into `"Hello "` (no exclamation point) then you can simply do:

  ```
  p para.children.first.text # if you know that text is the first child
  p para.at('text()').text   # if you want to find the first text node
  ```

As @Iwe showed, you can use the `String#strip` method to removing leading/trailing whitespace from the result, if you like.

Comment: And `squeeze(' ')` to remove space runs from inside the string.

Answer (score 0):

There's a different way to go about this. Rather than bother with removing nodes, remove the text that those nodes contain:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<p>hello my website is <a href="www.website.com">click here</a> <b>test</b></p>')
text = doc.search('p').map{ |p|
  p_text = p.text
  a_text = p.at('a').text
  p_text[a_text] = ''
  p_text
}

puts text

>>hello my website is  test
```

This is a simple example, but the idea is to find the `<p>` tags, then scan inside those for the tags that contain the text you don't want. For each of those unwanted tags, grab their text and delete it from the surrounding text.

In the sample code, you'd have a list of undesirable nodes at the `a_text` assignment, loop over them, and iteratively remove the text, like so:

```
text = doc.search('p').map{ |p|
  p_text = p.text
  %w[a].each do |bad_nodes|
    bad_nodes_text = p.at(bad_nodes).text
    p_text[bad_nodes_text] = ''
  end
  p_text
}
```

You get back `text` which is an array of the tweaked text contents of the `<p>` nodes.